# Multiply Django field values to get a total

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Supplier(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.supplier.name

@property
def total(self):
    orderitems = self.product_set.all()
    total = sum([item.get_total for item in products])
    return total

class Product(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
costprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
retailprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
barcode = models.CharField(
    null=True, max_length=99, unique=True, blank=True)
supplier = models.ForeignKey(
    Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=5)
on_order = models.ForeignKey(
    Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
on_order_quantity = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('description',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.description
```

i've created an order object for a given supplier with two products, with different quantities and cost prices.

How do I multiply cost x qty and add up those values in order to reach a total order value?

this is my view

```
def PurchaseOrder(request, pk_order):
orders = Order.objects.get(id=pk_order)
products = Product.objects.filter(
    on_order_id=pk_order).prefetch_related('on_order')
total_products = products.count()
supplier = Product.objects.filter(
    on_order_id=pk_order).prefetch_related('on_order')
total_value = Product.objects.filter(
    on_order_id=pk_order).aggregate(Sum('costprice'))

context = {
    'supplier': supplier,
    'products': products,
    'orders': orders,
    'total_products': total_products,
    'total_value': total_value, }

return render(request, 'crmapp/purchase_order.html', context)
```

at the moment it returns this:

[image]

This is my html template

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'
Well, I need to show my code

```html
{% extends 'crmapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class='main-site>'>
<h4> Supplier: {{orders.supplier}}</h4>
<h5>Order Number: {{orders.id}}</h5>
<h5>Created on: {{orders.date_created | date:"d/m/Y"}}</h5>
<h6>Total Lines In Order: {{total_products}}</h6>
<button style='margin-bottom:10px' class='btn btn-primary' id="open-popup-1">Edit</button>
<button style='margin-bottom:10px' class='btn btn-success' href=""  id="open-popup-1">Print/Export</button>


      <input type="search" placeholder="Search any field..." class="form-control search-input" data-table="customers-list"/>
      <table class="table table js-sort-table mt32 customers-list" id='myTable'>
      <thead class="table" >
        <tr>
          <th class='header' onclick="sortTable(0)" scope="col">ID</th>
          <th class='header' onclick="sortTable(1)" scope="col">Description</th>
          <th class='header' onclick="sortTable(3)" scope="col">Order Quantity</th>
          <th class='header' onclick="sortTable(2)" scope="col">Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
      {% for product in products %}
          <td> <a href="{% url 'productpage' product.id %}">{{product.id}}</a></td>
          <td><h6><strong>{{product.description}}</strong></h6></td>
          <td>{{product.on_order_quantity |floatformat:0}}</td>
          <td>£{{product.costprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     {% endfor %}
     
  </table>
  <div class='ordertotal'>
  <h5>Order Value:</h5>
  <h6><strong>{{total_value}}</strong></h6>
  </div>
      
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: costprice should represent cost x qty for each product right? you could use use the property decorator? see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Answer (score 1):

Use the property decorator for the `costprice` field in the `Product` Model?

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    # define other fields here

    @property
    def costprice(self):
        "Returns retailprice * qty for each product."
        return self.on_order_quantity * self.retailprice
```

**Update**:

There's clearly some misunderstanding. Therefore I'll try to provide more information.

First Question: "How do I multiply cost x qty"

The `property` decorator allows you to create fields, which behave like calculated read_only fields. (You don't need to initialize them)

```py
    @property
    def cost_x_qty(self):
        "Returns costprice multiplied by qty for each product."
        return self.on_order_quantity * self.costprice
```

Second Question: "How do I add up those values in order to reach a total order value?"

You can use [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/) to do this.

You can do the following in your view function:

```py
def PurchaseOrder(request, pk_order):
    # some code
    grand_total = Product.objects.filter(
        on_order_id=pk_order).aggregate(Sum('cost_x_qty'))
    # add to context
    context['grand_total'] = grand_total
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

you can use the `grand_total` in your template file like this:

```
{{grant_total}}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: what should I put on the view and template to test it out?

Comment: total should be available at `total_value`

Comment: thanks, but I'm still not clear on what you mean.

Comment: the `property` decorator allows you to create fields, which behave like `calculated fields`. I assume that `on_order_quantity` is the quantity for each product in the shopping chart and `retailprice` is the price of the product!? Shopping charts usually contain `positions` (product and quantity). using the decorator approach, `costprice` will then be the price for each position

Comment: in your `PurchaseOrder` you sum up those `costprice`s (take a look at the `total_value` variable in the `PurchaseOrder` view in your question) and then you add it to the context, which makes it available in the template file under `total_value`

Comment: This would be a purchase order to a supplier, so the values I need to use are the cost, not retail, as I'm not selling to the public.  total_value is my attempt at calculating the total value that I would be paying said supplier for the products I'm buying... I can't figure out how to tell django to do the math: for each line calculate costprice x qty and add up those totals for a grand total and show that on the template.

Comment: can you add your template file?

Comment: added to question

Comment: does `product.costprice` work as expected?

Comment: product.costprice shows the correct value that I set when creating said product. so yes

Comment: grand_total = Product.objects.filter(
        on_order_id=pk_order).aggregate(Sum('cost_x_qty'))

This does not work

Cannot resolve keyword 'cost_x_qty' into field. Choices are: barcode, costprice, description, id, on_order, on_order_id, on_order_quantity, retailprice, supplier, supplier_id

I'm losing my will to live and to carry on with this project.... But thanks for your patience anyways.